# remove google-assets completely from the wordpress-site to meet GDPR-regulations

Tags: php, wordpress, api, google-maps

**update:** good news: i contacted the developer and they replied - that they are currently working on a solution:

concrete: the developer from astoundify.com sent me a mail:

cit:

> We will be soon adding an option to remove Google Maps usage
> completely. For Google Fonts, we have already provided an option to
> download the fonts locally, see
> https://kb.astoundify.com/article/how-to-ensure-your-jobify-theme-is-gdpr-compliant-with-google-fonts/
> on how to use it. Make sure you are using the latest version.

**well**: thats sounds great and very promising - and i hope that this will solve the issues. That sounds great and would be a awesome.
lets hope that. i will keep you up to date - i will repost all the new things and will update this thread as soon as possible.

see all - **the issue:** and the phenomenon: due to the challenging GDPR-regulations in Germany, I would like to remove Google maps completely from my website. Actually I do not use it with the theme jobify (see https://kb.astoundify.com/article/how-to-remove-maps-in-jobify-results-page/ )

The theme Jobify i use in combination with the plugin wp-jobmanager ( see.: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/ )

```
pulls content from  5 Domains 
    pulls data from 5 foreign Domains from so called third countries
```

tested with this Test-tool: https://www.ccm19.de/cookie-scanner/

```
    fetch https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces&language=en&ver=6.1.1
    
    stylesheet https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,60...
    
    script https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces&language=en&ver=6.1.1
    
    image: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/iw_close.gif
    
    xhr: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true
```

it seems that the site and the system is still using google maps as a source. How can I remove it completely to comply with the german GDPR?
In addition I would also like to get rid of the new em-search-group-type-list – especially the maps display option.  How can I do that?

**btw**; i allready tird what the jobfy-team suggested to do:

**How to Remove Maps in Jobify Results page**  https://kb.astoundify.com/article/how-to-remove-maps-in-jobify-results-page/

If you have your demo imported the most times you will have the Jobs results page indicating the map section at the top of the page. This simply displays the location of all the job listings within the map using pins. The maps display within this page because the template in use is the maps & results template. Therefore to remove the maps in the find a job page or simply the results page simply head over to edit the page and go to the page attributes on the right side, then under the dropdown select the default template instead. See the screenshot below

**approach:** i guess that  Google Maps is not included in WordPress core, so there's no general purpose solution. well the developer-documentation shows how to remove the map, but they're clearly still loading the Google Maps assets. We need to find out how to specifically remove those assets from the plugin.

Comment: do you have caching enabled? Did you clear your wordpress cache?

Comment: hello dear Frizzant - man thanks for the quick reply and this hint.  I will check this out. I did not have cleared the WordPress-cache yet. And yes: i will check the caching setting. I will reply later the day. Many thanks so far.